# eclipselink - put an object into history

Tags: java, eclipselink

Is there in eclipselink possibility to put an object into history, when object hasn't changed?

I'm using HistoryPolicy to keep object history, but there is problem when someone will modify object without stored history.
HistoryPolicy keeps only changed objects, but if sub-objects weren't changed (@manyToMany, @manyToOne annotations, etc...) then we don't have history for sub-object.
So... when we want to restore object from history we loose all informations about sub-objects.

That's why I want to save current object with his sub-objects to history before I'll write changes to database (if there is no history for this object).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your issue.  Whenever you persist an object with a HistoryPolicy EclipseLink will insert into both the main and the history table, you can never have an object that has no row in the history table.

Comment: I can have it when I insert from other app - ex. from liquibase during building, or when I'll import data from other system, or when some moron from helpdesk will create row by hand.